# The new navigation only shows the date asked, also when modified

Tags: bug, question-lists, new-nav

On the *Need answers* page in the new navigation it only shows the date the question was asked, not when it was modified or answered.

See this same question on MSE. It as asked 7 hours ago:

> [image: Need answers page]

It doesn't show it was recently edited. It was edited 3 hours ago, as you can see here.

> [image: the question]

Can this be fixed please?

(As an argument: the current UI does do the above as it should, see for example the [unanswered list on Seasoned Advised](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/unanswered), which didn't get the new UI yet).

Comment: That's because you're on newest isn't it?

Comment: @Tim no, same issue on *votes* or *ending*. Only *recently active* shows the date modified.